# Mean Value Theorem Q

Tags: calculus

If $h(x) = (f\circ g)(x), x\in [a,b]$, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous over $[a,b]$ and differentiable over $(a,b)$. And $g(a) = b, g(b) = a$. We need to show that there exists at least one $c \in (a,b)$ such that 
$$h(a)-h(b) = f'(c)(b-a)$$

I tried to use the mean value theorem and I got 
$$h(b)-h(a) = h'(c)(b-a)$$

Do you have any suggestions please

Comment: Make use of the condition about $g$.

Comment: Seems that $g([a,b] ) \subseteq [a,b] $ is presumed, otherwise $h$ might not be defined.

Answer (score 1):

It was easier than I expected

I have to apply the Mean Value Theorem on $f(x)$, then

there exists at least one $c \in (a,b)$ such that

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$$

Now, since $h(a) = (f \circ g) (a) = f(g(a)) = f(b)$

$h(b) = (f \circ g) (b) = f(g(b)) = f(a)$

then

$$f'(c) = \frac{h(a) - h(b)}{b-a}$$

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, if we assume $g([a,b]) \subseteq [a,b]$, then $h$ would be well-defined. Now use the condition about $g$, we write the equation we want to prove as 
$$
\frac {h(a) - h(b)} {g(a) - g(b)} = f'(c). 
$$
Now consider **Cauchy Mean Value Theorem**. If $g'\neq 0$ on $[a,b]$ is also presumed, then the equation is easily deduced. Otherwise this question would be much complicated.